# Сalculate the number of differences by lines in the csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Please HELP!! I need PYTHON code

There is a csv file with a large number of rows and columns.

It is necessary to calculate the number of differences by comparing each row with each other across all columns.

for example:
the row with id 12180 and row 12188 have differences in 3 columns, then the row with id 12180 is compared with the row with id 13371 and it is assumed that there are 1 difference between them,
and according to this principle it is necessary to compare all the rows in the file

| id | man_title | art | title | 10239 | 10240 | 10241 | 10242 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12180 | SDVQO | qw | 300 TDE XL C | 2 | ef | atm | 12 |
| 12188 | SDVQO | qw | VX 220 | 1 | ef | atm | rr4 |
| 13371 | SDVQO | qw | VX 200/4 H-C | 2 | ef | atm | 12 |

the result should be written to a new csv file, which will display the ID of the line that was compared and the ID of the line with which the differences were compared and found. the third column is the number of matches when comparing these rows

| id1 | id2 | differences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12180 | 12188 | 3 |
| 12188 | 13371 | 1 |

I tried to count the number of duplicates for each unique row, but that's not exactly what I need.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It means that no one will help me here, because this is all I have???\

Comment: if you explain what *"comparing each row with each other across all columns"* means, then maybe someone can help you. provide and example of what you want to achieve...

Comment: I'm so sorry that no one can understand this

Comment: That's because you don't describe the logic very well. For example, you're saying *"then the row with id 10243 is compared .."*. Where is `10243` in your example ? Also, can you explain the  number `5` here : *"id 12180 and row 12188 have differences in 5 columns.."* ?

Comment: @Timeless.  *"then the row with id 10243"*.  i was going to say exactly the same...  the question refers to data that does not exist !!

Comment: You want to compare row 1 to all others, then row 2 to all others etc... What is the `.shape` of your data frame?

Comment: i have voted to close the question as it is incomplete.

Comment: file csv, Shape of DataFrame: (257, 68)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution :

```
from itertools import combinations

combs = pd.DataFrame(combinations(df["id"], 2), columns=["id1", "id2"])

left = df.set_index("id").loc[combs["id1"]].reset_index()
right = df.set_index("id").loc[combs["id2"]].reset_index()

out = combs.assign(differences=left.ne(right).sum(axis=1).sub(1))
```

Or, since you have a [small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77324442/%D0%A1alculate-the-number-of-differences-by-lines-in-the-csv-file#comment136320695_77324442) df, one option is to self [`cross`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra) and compute the differences :

```
cross = (df.merge(df, how="cross", indicator=True,
         suffixes=("_l", "_r")).loc[lambda x: x[["id_l", "id_r"]]
            .agg(sorted, axis=1).duplicated()])

left = cross.filter(like="_l").drop("id_l", axis=1)
right = cross.filter(like="_r").drop("id_r", axis=1)

diff = left.ne(right.set_axis(left.columns, axis=1)).sum(axis=1)

out = (cross[["id_l", "id_r"]].set_axis(["id1", "id2"], axis=1)
        .assign(differences = diff).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

     id1    id2  differences
0  12180  12188            3
1  12180  13371            1
2  12188  13371            3
```

Comment: Tell me how to change the code if it is necessary not to display rows that differ in values ​​in column 3?

Comment: the condition is this: if when comparing rows in column 3 the values ​​do not match, then remove these rows from the output

Comment: I have a feeling that you're not sure about your expected output. Otherwise, you would ask that at first and not after getting an answer. By asking for a new output, your question becomes a **moving target** and I'm not sure I can address each of your following inquiries. That being said, make sure to update your post with a **meaningful example and a clear logic/expected output.**